# How to create left arrow in tikzcd?

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd

I want to make the arrows in the following code left, but it gives an error.

```
 \begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[rr,shift left,"\lambda"]
  \arrow[rr,shift right,swap,"\mu"]
&&
3 
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: That code works fine here, which error do you get? Do you mean that you want to do `1 &&\arrow[ll,shift left,"\lambda"]   \arrow[ll,shift right,swap,"\mu"] 3`?

Comment: "ı think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell"  şeklinde bi hata alıyorum

Comment: I made some simple changes, but I did not correct the error

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `\arrow[rr]`, that means to draw an arrow from the cell the `\arrow` is placed in, to the cell that is two columns right. `r` stands for "right", two `r`s mean two columns to the right. Similarly, `l` means left, `u` means up and `d` down. I'm assuming you tried something like

```
\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow[ll,shift left,"\lambda"]
  \arrow[ll,shift right,swap,"\mu"]
&&
3 
\end{tikzcd}
```

but that cannot work because the two arrows are placed in the first column, so there are no columns to the left. To use `ll` you have to move the arrows to the last column, i.e.

```
\begin{tikzcd}
1 && 3 
  \arrow[ll,shift left,"\lambda"]
  \arrow[ll,shift right,swap,"\mu"]
\end{tikzcd}
```

Another option is to add the `leftarrow` option to the arrows while keeping `rr`. This will move the arrow tip to the start of the line, instead of the end.

Unrelated note: As egreg mentioned in his comment below, using empty columns to add space is probably not the best approach, it would be better to modify the `column sep`. You can give a specific length (e.g. `column sep=1cm`) or use one of the predefined keys (`tiny`, `small`, `scriptsize`  `normal`, `large`, `huge`) to set the separation between columns.

Complete example with both options for the arrows, and `column sep=huge` instead of the empty column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge]
1 &
 \arrow[l,shift right,swap,"\lambda"]
 \arrow[l,shift left,"\mu"]
3  \\
1 
 \arrow[r,leftarrow,shift left,"\lambda"]
 \arrow[r,leftarrow,shift right,swap,"\mu"]
&
3 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It wasn't entirely clear what you wanted to do, or what you actually did, so I'm guessing a bit here.

Comment: There is no need to double the number of columns; I believe it's cleaner to act on `column sep`.

Comment: @egreg True, can't argue with that. (I remember you said the same on the OPs previous question.) Will edit my answer in a bit.